# Kubuntu 12.10 AMD 64-bit and Lubuntu 12.10 AMD 64-bit not booting through live USB on Dell Inspiron N5050 laptop

Tags: system-installation, dell

I tried to make a live USB of Lubuntu 12.10 and also of Kubuntu 12.10, but only the boot screen appears. When selected in live mode, the Kubuntu/Lubuntu start screen appears and suddenly stops booting.

I don't understand what the issue is. I tried different flash drives using Fedora USB Creator in UNetbootin. I also downloaded another iso, but had the same issue.

**Hardware overview**

This system was tested with these key components:

```
Processor
Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B940 @ 2.00GHz
Video
Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
Network
Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Network
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
```

The following components are contained in the Dell Inspiron 15 N5050 laptop -- which has been awarded the status of Certified for Ubuntu.

```
Audio
Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
Bluetooth
Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
CDROM
TSSTcorp DVD+-RW TS-L633J
Optiarc DVD+-RW AD-7717H
Unknown Optiarc DVD+/-RW AD-7717H
Capture
Suyin Corp. 064E:8123 (USB)
Unknown Intergrated Webcam
Disk
Unknown WDC WD5000BPVT-75HXZT1
PQI PQI USB Flash Drive
ADATA ADATA USB Flash Drive
MUSHKIN MKNUFDPR2GB
Generic- Multi-Card
Keyboard
Unknown AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
Mouse
Unknown DualPoint Stick
Unknown PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Unknown ImPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint
Network
Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
Other
Unknown i8042 KBD port
Unknown i8042 AUX port
Unknown HDA Intel PCH
Unknown Power Button
Unknown Video Bus
Unknown HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
Unknown HDA Intel PCH Mic at Ext Left Jack
Unknown HDA Intel PCH HP Out at Ext Left Jack
Sanyo DELL 4YRJH15
Unknown hci0
Unknown dell-wifi
SCSI
Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Power Quotient International Co., Ltd 3538:0901 (USB)
Kingston Technology Company Inc. 13FE:3600 (USB)
A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd. C906 Flash Drive
Touch
Unknown AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad
USB
Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
Unknown
Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Unknown 118C:0504 (PNP)
Unknown 0000 (ATA_DEVICE)
Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
PNP IBM Enhanced keyboard controller (101/2-key)
PNP 41D0:0A08 (PNP)
PNP AT Real-Time Clock
PNP Motherboard registers
PNP ACPI Control Method Battery
PNP ACPI power button device
PNP PCI interrupt link device
PNP 41D0:0C14 (PNP)
INT 25D4:340E (PNP)
Video
Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
Wireless
Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express
```

Comment: I think this is not the useful answer but, get a Windows laptop then open Rufus to create bootable disk using those ISO you have mention, cuz if I make a disk inside Ubuntu (or any Deb-based distros), it would fail all the time, I mean the computer just froze. Also, I think because of your CPU is not strong enough for those distros you've mention

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Linux Mint Cinnamon 64-bit on the same laptop, so it should work for you.

First check the ISO image to be sure it is the same as the one hosted on website (using MD5 checksum).

Then use that ISO file to make a bootable flashdrive using unetbootin.

Then change the boot order using the <kbd>F2</kbd> key - set USB to boot first.

Then reboot.

After installation is complete, change boot order back to HDD first.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a recent laptop it might have secure boot on by default. If that's so, have you tried to deactivate it in your UEFI settings (BIOS)?